# Nginx: (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use to Nginx for reverse proxy. I have 1 Node.js app on port 3333 and Golang app on port 3334. When calling to Golang API, I see this message in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2016/07/15 10:18:36 [error] 4835#0: *131 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 27.69.66.52, 
server: video1.techmaster.vn, 
request: "GET /stream/dash/5klRyUnPVyDWouxscIT42uWs5JL4x9nHFol9ecg5g0GLf7aTaI/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwcmljZSI6MCwiZnVsbCI6dHJ1ZSwidmlkZW8iOnsiaWQiOjEwODcsIm5hbWUiOiJtcDNaaW5nU2hvd0RhdGEtMjY0Lm1wNCIsInBhdGgiOiIvbWVkaWEvODIxNyJ9LCJhdHRhY2htZW50IjpbXSwiZXhwIjoxNDY4NTU2NTE2fQ.qc9d_XPhCepHf5iJyf9ORBPOo3pTvF8Th_VMadNSM2o/43f_vid_19.m4s HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3334/stream/dash/5klRyUnPVyDWouxscIT42uWs5JL4x9nHFol9ecg5g0GLf7aTaI/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwcmljZSI6MCwiZnVsbCI6dHJ1ZSwidmlkZW8iOnsiaWQiOjEwODcsIm5hbWUiOiJtcDNaaW5nU2hvd0RhdGEtMjY0Lm1wNCIsInBhdGgiOiIvbWVkaWEvODIxNyJ9LCJhdHRhY2htZW50IjpbXSwiZXhwIjoxNDY4NTU2NTE2fQ.qc9d_XPhCepHf5iJyf9ORBPOo3pTvF8Th_VMadNSM2o/43f_vid_19.m4s", 
host: "video1.techmaster.vn", 
referrer: "https://techmaster.vn/khoa-hoc-online/8217/lap-trinh-ios-swift/96/Location-Notification"
```

I don't know what's the problem from. Maybe I have done some mistake in Nginx config. Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
listen  80;
server_name video1.techmaster.vn www.video1.techmaster.vn;
return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 spdy ssl;
server_name video1.techmaster.vn www.video1.techmaster.vn;
keepalive_timeout 30;

# Allow upload video up to 100M
client_max_body_size 100M;

# Config SSL
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/sv.video1.techmaster.vn.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_session_cache  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "xxxxxxxxxx";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
ssl_stapling on;

location ~* /.*\.(xml)$      {
    root /var/www/videos.techmaster.vn/public;
    expires 7d;
}

location /stream/ {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3334;

    set $cors '';

    if ($http_origin ~* (localhost|www\.techmaster\.vn|techmaster\.vn)) {
        set $cors 'true';
    }

    if ($cors = 'true') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Range';
    }
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;

    set $cors '';

    if ($http_origin ~* (localhost|www\.techmaster\.vn|techmaster\.vn)) {
        set $cors 'true';
    }

    if ($cors = 'true') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Range';
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited Nginx config and it works

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name 192.168.1.10;
    keepalive_timeout 30;

# Config SSL
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m; 
ssl_session_cache  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    ssl_stapling on;

# Allow upload video up to 100M
    client_max_body_size 100M;

location ~* /.*\.(xml)$      {
        root /var/www/videos.techmaster.vn/public;
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /stream/* {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3334;

        set $cors '';

        if ($http_origin ~* (localhost|tech\.dev)) {
                set $cors 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = 'true') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Range';
        }
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;

    set $cors '';

        if ($http_origin ~* (localhost|tech\.dev)) {
                set $cors 'true';
        }

    if ($cors = 'true') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Range';
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you've changed and why? I have a similar issue with a different application.

Comment: @Folatt i changed `location /stream/` to `location /stream/*`

Answer (score 2):

I had got same issue while configuring AWS with node platform.

I  used 3000 port to start the application.
When I changed my port to 8081 it worked.